# Update item or create new if does not exist C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Say there is a job record that belongs to a person, in the first foreach statement we are just updating the info we always already have - this works fine and as intended.

For the second foreach statement, `JobTasks` is something we **may** already have info on or not, so the intended behaviour is to check if the ID is present, if not add it like it's being created for the first time.

```
private void UpdateAnswers(Job job)
{
    foreach (var item in job.JobInfo)
    {
        _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    foreach (var item in job.JobTasks)
    {
        _db.Entry(item).State = item.JobID == 0 ?
                                   EntityState.Added :
                                   EntityState.Modified; 
    }
}
```

When I proceed further trying to add it for the first time it does not add the record in the table `JobTasks`. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Following would help you. You should attach or update the entity, isn't it?

```
private void UpdateAnswers(Job job)
    {
        foreach (var item in job.JobInfo)
        {
            _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.Entry.Update(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in job.JobTasks)
        {
          
            if(item.JobID != 0)
            {
              _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
              _db.Entry.Update(item);
            }else{
               _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
               _db.Entry.Add(item);
            }                                  
        }
       //Save Changes
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Getting cannot implicitly convert type bool to system.data.entity.entitystate error on the if statement

Comment: both the _db.Entry.Update(item); line and the _db.Entry.Add(item); throw the following error '...Is a 'method' which is not valid in the given context' error

Comment: It is the idea, you should find the way how it should be implemented according to your code.